# What is a good statistics library for computing multiple correlations in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, statistics

I am writing an application to automate some financial analysis and need to compute multiple correlations.  Currently, I am using MathNet.Numerics for computing single correlations, but it doesn't have the ability to compute multiple correlations as far as I can tell.  Are there any .NET libraries that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might need some R:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/RtoCSharp.aspx

Comment: Nice article on using R within .NET.  It looks like this may be the only choice.